# How to use fat jar for different hue workflows

Tags: java, hadoop, cloudera, oozie, hue

My intention is to use one `fat jar` for many different hue managed `oozie` jobs by calling its different main classes.

Everything works just fine if I put it in every respective workflow directory like this:

```
/user/hue/oozie/workspaces/hue-oozie-1439883696.08/myJobs.jar
```

But I cant figure out where I am supposed to put it, so all workflows can access it. Always getting an `java.lang.ClassNotFoundException`, as oozie cant find the jar.

```
/user/hue/oozie/workspaces/workflows/jobname/lib/myJobs.jar
```

looked promising, but doesn't seem to be right, too.

Comment: Did you vote my question into oblivion because I forgot to use code tags, or because you think it is a bad question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do You have Installed Shared Lib for Oozie, I belive You having Shared Lib Enabled by parameter like "

> oozie.use.system.libpath = true

in the properties of Jobs, after Instaling Shared Lib Location in HDFS and place the Jar It Will Work.

Also Anothere Option: Check The Hadoop ClassPath Confiuration. 
If The Fat Jar Local Location,is available in Local Nodes and the CLassPath need to be updated with the Same Local location and hadoop need to be restart to take the effect, then start the Oozie Job, and check Job Console the Required Jar should be reflecting there.

Comment: Thank you Debjit, that was very helpful. I decided against adding my jars into the shared lib folder, as cloudera disencourages this practice. By adding `oozie.libpath=/path/to/jars/` to my job.properties I was able to get it to work. [Cloudera article for reference](http://blog.cloudera.com/blog/2014/05/how-to-use-the-sharelib-in-apache-oozie-cdh-5/)